# Interchangeably: You're supposed x You should

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, modality

Can I use "should" rather than "you're supposed"?

> Aren't you supposed to give him anesthectic?
>
> Shouldn't you give him anesthetic?

Comment: My bad! Updated now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the context, but in general, *you're supposed* indicates an expectation something will happen.
*should* just indicates a belief of what needs to happen.

> Aren't you **supposed** to give him anesthetic?

Here I expect that he needs the anesthetic. But I don't know what you will do.
See [***suppose***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/suppose):

> 5) to expect or obligate (*always in the passive*)"   *⇒ you're supposed to telephone*"

As for:

> **Shouldn't** you give him anesthetic?

Here I am just asking if he needs the anesthetic. Nothing more without more context.

Comment: Is there a synonymous, or something that I could use as interchangeably?

Comment: For which one?.

Comment: When I saw this sentence in the The Simpsons's episode, the character doesn't created an expectation, I guess, kinda She warned about the anesthetic

Comment: For "you're supposed"

Comment: I added some info. to my answer. I think "expect" is closest but maybe any synonym on the linked page after "presume". You have to judge based on the context.

Comment: Actually, that was more clarify, to expect or obligate.